# libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, codeblocks

After downloading GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ)-32 bit for SFML for codeblocks, I can build and run but can not run .exe files. Whenever i try to run .exe files, an error message shows up: "The program can't start because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. " I tried going to settings->compilers -> linker settings -> other linker settings -> added -shared-libgcc and -shared-libstdc++ , but same error message shows up still. Can anyone help me? I may need specific answers because I am a newbie. I spent hours trying to figure this out...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks

Comment: Why not simply using MinGW gcc? Also you need to ensure that the `%PATH%` environment variable contains the directory where the GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) DLLs were installed.

Comment: I did already include the path variable, and in sfml tutorial page, it is said that TDM is better for code blocks (mingw)

Comment: There's 64-bit support with MinGW gcc meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As always on Windows, any DLL with which a program is linked at buildtime
must be found *at runtime* by the OS program loader in one of the directories
where it looks for DLLs as per the Windows [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

Therefore make sure that `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` is in one of those
directories. The crudest way of doing this is to copy the DLL to
the same directory that contains the program. This DLL is your GCC compiler's runtime library, and you will find it in `<Your_TDM_GCC_Install_Dir>/bin` - e.g. `C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin`

Comment: I can not find libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll anywhere in the sfml folder

Comment: @Berry Why on earth would you expect it to be in the SFML folder??

Comment: @Berry Directions added.